# "Childish", "puerile" and "juvenile" which is more derogative?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

In order to scorn someone's behaviour, excuse etc., we can define it as *childish* or *puerile*, *juvenile*. In my register, they are graded down in that order. Is it right, or is there any difference in meaning or connotation?

Eg.,

> "*That was a rather childish/ puerile excuse.*"

Comment: And don't forget _callow_ and _jejune_.

Comment: Even *sophomoric*.

Comment: @SvenYargs *callow*, *jejune* may not be derogatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Childish* is primarily neutral, with a secondary meaning that is pejorative: "silly and immature". *Puerile* is pejorative *per se*, with no "respectable" sense of use. *Juvenile*, like *childish* is first and foremost a neutral term, with a mildly derogatory secondary meaning.

That puts them in the order: *juvenile, childish* and *puerile* in the degree of increasing derogatoriness.

Ref: [ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: *Childish* and *juvenile* are not usually neutral when applied to adults. I don't think they can be definitely ordered, it's somewhat subjective and some would put those two the other way around. I agree that *puerile* is the most derogatory.

Answer (score 2):

Puerile is highly insulting, juvenile is somewhat less so and childish not quite so bad. If someone is using British/Australian English and calls you puerile, they probably consider your behavior somewhat repugnant.

Comment: This would benefit from a source and correct spelling.  Please see the [tour].

Answer (score -5):

They are all synonyms of each other, having the same meaning.  In American English, they are all interchangeable.

On a different note, at least in America, very few people will know what puerile means.  It is not a word in most people's vocabulary.

Comment: They are synonyms, but that doesn't make them completely interchangeable, they don't have *exactly* the same meaning.